# Some PHP functions work on localhost, but not VPS

Tags: php

these lines of code work fine on my localhost, but not on my VPS hosting:

```
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$videoID;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load($url);
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue; 
$description = $doc->getElementsByTagName("description")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I can't figure out why they would work on localhost and not my vps which is set up like the exact same as localhost.

Comment: Your VPS either has a different version of PHP (potentially < version 5) or DomDocument extension was disabled when your PHP was compiled.

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: it has 5.3.3 installed.my localhost has 5.3.6

Comment: Please **define "doesn't work"**. What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: No error shows, it just stops everything beyond that part of the script from working.

Comment: Please post you PHP version, DOM version and libxml version from a) your localhost and b) your server. you can find these information runngin an php script <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: PHP: Localhost - 5.3.6, VPS - 5.3.3, libxml: Localhost - 2.7.8, VPS - 2.7.6 

I couldn't find DOM, but this is the info: http://199.192.203.137/phpinfo.php

Comment: Please enable error reporting either by putting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the init of your code. Also was your localhost in Windows? there are some incompatibilities in windows and linux compiled versions of PHP (Thats really very less)

Comment: My localhost is Mac, but it looks like the error is with DOM being disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://199.192.203.137/phpinfo.php

DOM is [explicitly disabled](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php) there: `--disable-dom`.

Either contact your host and ask them to enable DOM (unlikely), use a different host or rewrite your code using another DOM/XML library.

Comment: What are the reasons why it would be disabled? What security things could be involved?

Comment: @DylanCross not necessarily security issue, you should ask your hosting provider provide you with the DOM enabled php binary, or do it yourself.

Comment: @Dylan Some hosts just don't want to deal with too many dependencies and only support the bare minimum configuration, others do it because "that's what most people use", others have no good reasons at all. Talk to your host.